# Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DIST_L2'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to use `cv2.distanceTransform()` method in Python. And I am getting an error when running the following line of code:

```
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,5)
```

I get the following error when running this code:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DIST_L2'

Similar questions have been asked before, and i know that  this problem occurs when you import 'something' when your python file name is 'something.py'.
However, my python file name is segment3.py.

Can anyone please help me with this? I am trying to do segmentation using watershed algorithm.
I am working on Fedora20.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google didn't turn up anything called `DIST_LT2`. Are you sure the thing you're looking for exists and has this name?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with OpenCV, but are you sure you didn't mean:  `cv2.DIST_L2` instead of `cv2.DIST_LT2`?

Comment: really sorry about it.. Yes it is cv2.DIST_L2
but the error is same, its just a typing error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Should be rewritten as below:

```
(dist_transform, labels) = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,5)
```

Comment: I got only one ret value though, so I had to write
dist_ransform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening2,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,5)

Answer (score 15):

Instead of `cv2.DIST_L2`, use:

```
cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2
```

I was having the same problem, but after some research, the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#distancetransform) mention an example file on the source code (opencv_source/samples/python2/distrans.py) which uses this constant instead. I tested here and it worked as expected.

Comment: its still not working. but why is this problem coming anyway? DIST_L2 is there in opencv

Comment: @Vartika Are you getting the same error? or is the resulting image just different than the expected?

Comment: nope, not the same Error but I am getting no Image.
The error is -
  File "vpython/segment3.py", line 32, in <module>
    dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,5)
cv2.error: /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-2.4.7/modules/imgproc/src/distransform.cpp:723: error: (-210) source image must be 8uC1 and the distance map must be 32fC1 (or 8uC1 in case of simple L1 distance transform) in function cvDistTransform

Comment: BTW, distanceTransform will return 'tuple', not only 'dist_transform'.
Like,
(dist_transform, labels) = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,5)

Answer (score 11):

This is a late reply, but in order to get through the tutorial you are doing, you really need to install openCV 3.0. Then the syntax in the tutorial is correct.

For openCV 3.0:

```
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
```

For openCV 2.x:

```
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

The next bug you will run into in completing the tutorial is `cv2.connectedComponents` not being available.  See [OpenCV for Python - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connectedComponents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699766/opencv-for-python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-connectedc).

The trick is to install opencv3, which can easily be done with [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) using

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

Answer (score 0):

cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2 works as a replacement